# Does gcloud cpu quota itself cost anything?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

For a gcloud project, by default there are about 72 cpus in that region and 
one can ask for more quota later on.

I wonder if the quota itself is free? If we can ask for more cpus, then what is the point of using quota?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing quotas is free. You need, however, to provide a good business justification on why you need more of certain resource (CPUs in your case) that those the default quotas allow.

Having said that, quotas are important, to guarantee resource availability for GCP customers and for preventing unforeseen spikes in usage.